# Why am I getting an undefined method error in rails after I check if method exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, methods, instance-variables, exists

On my user profile page in my rails app, I am recieving the error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

I know it is because of the following 3 lines of code:

```
<% if @user.profile.title %>
     <%= @user.profile.title %>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand why.  Since i use the if statement, shouldn't it first check whether title exists, then if it exists display it, and if it does not exist, it should not display it.  What is wrong and how do I fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `title` is nil you can't test against it like you did. 
Try:

```
<% if @user.profile.try(:title) @user.profile.title %>
```

Comment: I think you can simplify this to `<%= @user.profile.try(:title) %>`

Comment: Was just doing it when you commented ;)

Comment: Couple of points to note here: It's not the `title` that's nil here, it's the profile.  Secondly, your solution does not print out the title, @DamienRoche's solution does.  Suggest editing your answer.

Comment: @vinodadhikary if profile is nil, the try will return nil: `nil.try(:name) # => nil`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes, which I believe is what we want in this case instead of an error the OP is getting.  But the points in my comment are a little different than how you interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
<% if @user.profile.present? %>
  <%= @user.profile.title %>
<% end %>
```

Or with try:

```
<%= @user.profile.try(:name) %>
```

With a default value if no profile associated:

```
<%= @user.profile.try(:name) || 'No profile for this user' %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer was correct, but Leonid was correct as well and answered first.  But I did vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not correctly. If you want to get access to some parameter from user you have to use direct access. But if you want to use profile that belongs to User model look at this 
[link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)